# How can i achieve this multiple threading scenario of file scanner?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to achieve this:

In my application, i will have a single thread(producer) which will do some processing from user input(the directory user want to crawl) and add all the name of folders in that directory into a linkedBlockingQueue named A, and at the same time while producer is adding into A, multiple consumer thread lets say 2, will be taking out the folder name of what is in A. Each consumer thread will take out one object at a time, processing it and put into another priorityBlockingQueue named B.

I now having issue with the threads, what i have done now:

main:

```
Thread[] workerThreads = new Thread[numOfThreads];

for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
    /* for each thread to concurrently retrieving directories from the workQueue 
     *  and placing data into another structure(matchQueue)*/
    workerThreads[i] = new Thread(new WorkerThread(workQueue, matchQueue, pattern));
    workerThreads[i].start();
    // System.out.println("Thread "+ i +" Started");
}   

Thread mainThread = new Thread(new ProducerThread(workQueue, args));
mainThread.start();
// System.out.println("Main Thread Started");



// when threads done, join them together
for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
    try {
        workerThreads[i].join();
        System.out.println("worker thread " + i + "joined");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

my producer thread:

```
public class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> workQueue;
    private String[] args;

    public ProducerThread(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> workQueue, String[] args) {
        this.workQueue = workQueue;
        this.args = args;
    }

    public void run() {
        // process every argument sequentially
        // for(String arg : args)
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            processDirectory(args[i]);
             if(i==args.length-1){
          fileCrawler.producerFinished = true;
      }         
}
    }
}
```

my worker thread:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> workQueue;
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> matchQueue;
    private String pattern;

    public WorkerThread(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> workQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue<String> matchQueue, String pattern) {
        this.workQueue = workQueue;
        this.matchQueue = matchQueue;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public void run() {
        do{
    String currentWorkToProcess = "";
    try{
    currentWorkToProcess = workQueue.take();
    System.out.println("Workerthread took from WorkQueue: " + currentWorkToProcess);

    }catch(InterruptedException e1){
        System.out.println(e1.toString());
    }


    File dir = new File(currentWorkToProcess);
    String[] files = dir.list();
    //System.out.println(pattern);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    for (String file : files)
    {

        File currentFile = new File(currentWorkToProcess + "/" + file);

        if(currentFile.isFile())
        {   //if current file is a file
            //create a matcher against that line of input
            //System.out.println(file);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file);

            if (m.matches()){
                System.out.println("File to be added: "+currentFile.getName());
                matchQueue.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
}while(!fileCrawler.producerFinished);

}

}
```

There are currently 3 issues which i do not know how to rectify, firstly my sequence is wrong, now my main thread add everything finish already then my worker thread will start taking out.They are not working at the same time. Secondly, my worker thread haven finish processing all the files within folder, they are joined and it ends. By right should have 8 files. Thirdly, how do i determine if my producer has ended what it is suppose to do and how to determine both my worker thread are done?

Sorry for the very lengthy post...not too gd with threads.Very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your ordering is simply a race condition - your producer thread has added all the directory names to the queue before your worker threads have even got started. If you want to prove this just add some sleeps into the main thread's loop.

Your worker threads are not processing all files because you have no loop in them. They simply take one item and then finish.

For monitoring your main thread you could simply join to it as well, or add a wait like this:

```
while(mainThread.isAlive()) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

I would also consider using the java.util.concurrent ExecutorService functionality rather than managing your own worker threads. You could then have your main thread create a Callable for each directory task and pass it to the executor service which would be a lot simpler. Here is a minimal example of doing that:

```
public class FileProcessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Thread mainThread = new Thread(new ProducerThread(executorService));
        mainThread.start();
    }

    public static class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
        private ExecutorService executorService;

        public ProducerThread(ExecutorService executorService) throws InterruptedException {
            this.executorService = executorService;
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(File f: new File("c:/").listFiles()) {
                if(f.isDirectory()) {
                    try {
                        final String fileName = f.getCanonicalPath();
                        executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public Object call() throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("Processing: " + fileName);
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
                        System.out.println("Added: " + f.getCanonicalPath());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am really sorry to say i really dont get you. i have make some adjustment by starting my consumer thread before my producer thread. and it will now take when there is something added to my workQueue. This is what i wanted but they only take once then they stop le. I do not know what codition to put in my while loop for my workerThread.

Comment: executor service example added - this gets rid of having to manage your own worker threads.

Comment: can i dont use executor service? I dont think i am allowed to. i know i am almost there but now the issue is my worker thread wont keep loop to take out from workqueue. Btw thanks for ur help

Comment: Not allowed to? Is it a college assignment? I'd start by asking why they are teaching bad programming practice if they object. If you really need to use worker threads then your loop will need to be something like "while(mainThread.isAlive() || workQueue.size() > 0)"

Comment: Actually, I can see why it might be useful to teach low level thread handling, so long as it's clear that this is to understand how threads work rather than because you should actually write code like this.

Comment: thanks after reading ur suggestion i think i get it already. thanks. i need a do while loop ffor my workerThread run(). and the codition to the while is to check if my producer produced finished already. thanks alot.

Comment: do you know how to unblock my take()? After adding a do while condition, my second thread is in the block process and doesnt recover. i think thats becuz it enter the do body before the condition is updated by the main thread

Comment: You could use poll() instead of take() [see java docs for details] Yet more fiddly stuff that the executor service avoids :-)

Comment: i would like to use take() because of its blocking functions. So if my producer thread is not done yet, my worker thread will be block till an element comes in(which is inserted by my producer) this is exactly what i wanted. However this also resulted in one of the thread in a forever blocking process. i have updated my new code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66018/discussion-between-10e5x-and-barrysw19).